# Javascript: innerHTML undefined

Tags: javascript

So I am doing something like this...

```
var crypto = tradeMsg.coin
var oldPrice;

for (let i=0; i<500; i++) {
  var compare = cryptoSName[i].innerHTML
  if (compare == crypto) {

    document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML= "$" + (tradeMsg.message.msg.price.toFixed(4));;
    document.getElementById('perc' + i).innerHTML= tradeMsg.message.msg.perc + "%";
    var newPrice = tradeMsg.message.msg.price

    if (newPrice<oldPrice) {
      document.getElementById("cryptotable" + i).style.background = "#ffe5e5";
      console.log(oldPrice)
    }
    else if (newPrice>oldPrice) {
      document.getElementById("cryptotable" + i).style.background = "green";

    }
    console.log(oldPrice);
    console.log(newPrice);
    var oldPrice = tradeMsg.message.msg.price

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("cryptotable" + i).style.background = "white"
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

When I `console.log` old price, it shows undefined, whereas I was expecting a previous value here. I have a feeling that I am having problem with Hoisting here.

I would be very much grateful, if anyone could help here?

Can someone also  explain me meaning of this..

> JavaScript's scopes are function-level, not block-level, and creating
>   a closure just means that the enclosing scope gets added to the
>   lexical environment of the enclosed function

Comment: You `console.log` `oldPrice` *before* you assign anything to it initially, so it'll be undefined the first time...? What else would you expect to happen

Comment: In your code, variable `oldPrice;` has not been initialized. So, calling `console.log( oldPrice )` will result in `undefined`

Comment: you have three different questions.. one in the title, a completely unrelated one about logging, and another one about scope. one question per question please. you can ask as many questions as you want... separately.

Comment: Your code looks like this: `var oldPrice;
for (let i=0; i<500; i++) {
  var oldPrice;` because of using var inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oldPrice variable need to declare in initial time then check